# Permission is denied for tmux

Tags: macos, terminal, tmux

I'm in OS X and running the `tmux` command provides me permission error:

```
$ tmux 
error creating /private/tmp/tmux-502 (Permission denied)
```

I use `brew` to uninstall and re-install `tmux` but the issue permitted.

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the command that solved the issue for me:

```
$ sudo chmod -R 700 /private/tmp/tmux-502
```